# page redirection or forward with time delay using servlet

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, servlets

When a servlet is called (says, servlet A), and I want to redirect to another html file or servlet file, I will use response.sendRedirect("URL"). However, what I want now is I want to display a page (says, Page B)giving some message to users and redirect with time delay, says, 3 seconds, to another page (says, Page C) for other actions. What should I do in servlet A to achieve the purpose. Page A and Page B can be html files or codes generated by servlet.

and also what would be the proper method if i just wanna forward instead of redirecting

Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 1):

On the page B you can do:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){document.location = 'page3.html'}, 3000)">
```